# How to use ServiceExtensions in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I was implementing Repository pattern using [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/net-core-20-with-angular-4-and-mysql-part-4-reposi).

I have to change **ConfigureServices** in **startup.cs** by adding below. Then I have created **ServiceExtensions** class and add above method. However it is still showing error.

[image]

ServiceExtensions Class is below

[image]
Is there a way to Create ServiceExtensions class or Is there any answer or some article/blog regarding this.

Comment: You missed a step to create the ServiceExtensions class and put that extension method in there. Look for "ServiceExtensions" in that article

Comment: I have tried. Is there a way to create ServiceExtensions Class?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Did you include namespace to the extension class?

Comment: It is working...@FCin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following that guide:

In the file *ServiceExtensions.cs*

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class ServiceExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureMySqlContext(this IServiceCollection services, 
                                                      IConfiguration config)
        {
            var connectionString = config["mysqlconnection:connectionString"];
            services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(o => o.UseMySql(connectionString));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you use it in the file *Startup.cs*:

```
services.ConfigureMySqlContext(Configuration);
```

Comment: @LahiruGamage You create it. Right-click on your project -> Add... -> Class